# Turn values of dictionnary into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The groups_per_user function receives a dictionary, which contains group names with the list of users. Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a dictionary with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values.

This is what I did but I didn't get the expected result.

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
user_groups = {}
for group, users in group_dictionary.items():
    for user in users
            if user not in user_groups:
                new_user_groups = {user: group}
                user_groups.update(new_user_groups)
            else:
                user_groups[user] += group
    return(user_groups)
print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
          "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
          "administrator": ["admin"] }))

 # it gave me this:
 {'admin': 'localpublicadministrator', 'userA': 'local', 'userB': 'public'}

 #but I want this:
 {'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
                new_user_groups = {user: group}
                user_groups.update(new_user_groups)
            else:
                user_groups[user] += group
```

to

```
                user_groups[user] = [group]
            else:
                user_groups[user].append( group )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how we can simplify this. First, we'll get a set of all usernames.

```
>>> d = {"local": ["admin", "userA"],
...           "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
...           "administrator": ["admin"] }
>>> set(x for lst in d.values() for x in list(lst))
{'userB', 'admin', 'userA'}
>>> users = set(x for lst in d.values() for x in list(lst))
```

Now, we'll use a dictionary comprehension along with `d` and `users`. And a list comprehension inside to find all of the roles associated with a given username.

```
>>> {name: [k for k, v in d.items() if name in list(v)] for name in users}
{'userB': ['public'], 'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local']}
>>>
```